# Jquery drop down menu not working after ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

so I'm trying to work with jquery and ajax and ran into a problem.

In short a drop down menu is created once a user is authenticated and logged in.

Ajax rewrites the menu holder with the correct menu options. The problem is that it works when the page is refreshed (CTRL+R), but not when the ajax rewrites the menu.

If I understand correctly this is because ajax writes after the page is loaded (DOM is complete) so because the menu and options weren't there (because the user hadn't successfully logged in) when the page DOM finished loading then the jquery can't find the new elements?

After reading around I saw this is usually because the .on Click is binded to an element and not the docment?

I've tried a hundred combinations now but still unsuccessful so I'm asking for some help to resolve this from any competent Jquery gurus out there :)

Here's the code...(I'm using jquery 1.10)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function DropDowna(el) {
            this.ddc = el;
            this.placeholder = this.ddc.children('span');
            this.opts = this.ddc.find('ul.dropdownmk > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDowna.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.ddc.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var ddc = new DropDowna( $('#ddc') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
            });

        });

</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div id="mmenuoptions">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="member">My Page</a></li><li><a href="#" class="member">Wish List (0)</a></li><li><a href="#" class="member">Help</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

The HTML gets rewritten by Ajax to

```
<div class="mymenuz">       
    <ul class="cbp-tm-menu">
    <li>        
        <div id="ddc" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
            <span>My Menu</span>
                <ul class="dropdownmk">                         
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-profile"></i>Option 1</a></li>                       
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit-profile"></i>Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-store"></i>Option 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-purchases"></i>Option 4</a></li>                     
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-items"></i>Option 5</a></li>                     
                </ul>
        </div>              
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="member">Wish List (0)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="member">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And thanks to any and all for their help, input and time. This has been killing me :(

Comment: You just need to run `var ddc = new DropDowna( $('#ddc') );` again after you modify the page.  It will only affect an element on the page with that ID at the time you run it.  If you remove that element and then add another one, by rewriting the html, then the effects of that function will be gone as well.

Comment: Hi Archer, do you mean have ajax "write" var ddc = new DropDowna( $('#ddc') ); at the same time it writes the new html? I.e. add <script>var ddc = new DropDowna( $('#ddc') );</script> to the ajax html?

Comment: If you post the ajax call then I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: Hi Archer, it's just returning <% Response.write("the html code")%> as the site is written in classic asp so the jquery is       function OnLogInCheckAvailability() 
{ 
if(oRequest.readyState == 4) 
{ 
if(oRequest.status == 200) 
{
if(oRequest.responseText !== "") 
{  
document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = oRequest.responseText;

} 
} 
else 
{ 
document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = "Asychronous Error";

Comment: Where the oRequest.responseText is <% Response.write("the rewritten html code with the menu ddc etc")%>

Comment: So you're posting html into the head when you get a successful response from your ajax call?

Comment: Yes. That's it exactly.

Comment: And the posted html overwrites the initial html which is loaded when the page first loads.

Comment: You shouldn't have html in the head tag at all.

Comment: Sorry Archer, there's a misunderstanding its not the <head> tag it's a div. <div id="head">

Comment: Should have made that clear...sorry if I'm causing confusion. The responseText is to <div id="head">. The original HTML is <div id="head"><div id="mmenuoptions"> etc etc </div></div> and this is replaced by <div id="head"><div class="mymenuz"> etc etc </div></div>

Comment: The line after `response.write(...);` add `ddc = new DropDowna($('#ddc'));` so that it initialises the dropdown with the new html you have inserted.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't rewrite the whole block of code.  You'd just send back the data you need to recreate the list items.  Returning the html for the whole element is what's actually causing your problem.

Comment: Since it's asp Archer being sent back, I closed response.write(...) with the %> and added <script>ddc = new DropDowna($('#ddc'));</script> underneath but nothing happened. So I wondered if it is because the oRequest.responseText; only gets the Response.write(...) and nothing more? So then I tried adding the ddc = new DropDowna($('#ddc')); as the line directly beneath document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = oRequest.responseText; in the jquery but still nothing :(

Comment: Got to say that it's a bit of a kick in the teeth to get a -1 and see it says the question doesn't show any research effort when I've been trying to solve this all day and don't actually have any experience with jquery or ajax.

Comment: Trim down your response so that it just sends back the list items and then use `$(".dropdownmk").html(oRequest.responseText);`

Comment: Thanks Archer. Really appreciate the feedback it's just that I can't trim the response so I'll need to try to find another way to resolve this. Appreciate your input and knowledge.

Comment: Not a problem - Can you post the full ajax call and response handler in the question? I'll look at trimming the response, but I need that script in full before I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved this myself after some more hours of torture but thought I should share the answer in case other users run into similar problems validating on click controls with Jquery after an Ajax update.

Basically, the code is good (everything being relative and @Archer has a point about trimming the code being parsed by Ajax)...but there are 2 main problems.

Firstly,  obj.ddc.on('click', function(event){  cannot fire because ddc is created AFTER DOM has completed. To get round this I bind the on click event to the document hence promising there will be a future div id called "ddc". So solution to problem one is

replace

obj.ddc.on('click', function(event){

with

$(document).on("click", "#ddc", function(e) {

Then problem two...Now the drop down menu is clickable and states active, it cannot retain the selection. Again this is because this.placeholder is defined before the Ajax update and no span tag exists when the DOM is loaded.

To get round this two changes. Again, obj.opts.on('click',function(){ needs to be redefined to work with the ajax injected HTML and the click bound once again at document level to.

$(document).on("click", "li", function() {

And then the placeholder needs to be defined. Created simply by adding obj.placeholder = $('.wrapper-dropdown-3 > span');

So the final Jquery

```
function DropDowna(el) {
            this.ddc = el;
            this.placeholder = this.ddc.children('span');
            this.opts = this.ddc.find('ul.dropdownmk > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDowna.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;
                $(document).on("click", "#ddc", function(e) {
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                $(document).on("click", "li", function() {
                /*obj.opts.on('click',function(){*/
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();                       
                    obj.placeholder = $('.wrapper-dropdown-3 > span');
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() { 

            var ddc = new DropDowna( $('#ddc') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
            });

})
```

Works perfectly and more importantly saved a bunch of time on rewriting code.

Thanks to @Archer for feedback during my problem.

Hope some of this logic and rewrites help anyone suffering from jquery / ajax updates and non-functioning links.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: `.click()` is a jQuery shorthand method for `.on("click")`.  This change won't make any difference.

Comment: @Archer. hmm, that did occur to me, I'm trying to think how he can be sure that the event will also work for newly created elements as I suspect thats the issue

Comment: `$(document)` won't change, so the click event handler will always run when he clicks something on the page, whether it existed at the time of adding that handler or not.

Comment: Hi guys, $(document).on('click',function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
}); would hopefully remove the class once it's been added.  Unfortunately, the class "active" doesn't get added until I refresh the page (then the removeClass also works) so the problem seems to be with obj.ddc.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });
Or maybe it is with initEvents : function()?